# Make presented view controller to ignore and pass through touch events

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, touch, viewcontroller

edit: I want to make this view independent to be reusable.

The question explains itself. I have searched, but didn't find any answers, even if the question seems to be common.

I have two view controllers `VC1` and `VC2`. My code is like:

```
VC1.present(VC2, animated: true)
```

Then, I need my `VC2` to totally ignore all touches and pass them through.

Good example is AppStore rating success alert (attached). You can scroll even when alert is presented, I need the same behavior.
[image]

Comment: Can I get any help here?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an `UIView` and just overlay it over your `VC1`. Then the `VC1` stays scrollable even when the `UIView` is presented

Comment: I want to make this view independent to be reusable.